# Phonegap Push Plugin. Open a particular app view after clicking the notification

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm using [Push Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) to receive notifications on a Phonegap app made for Android and iOS. The notifications are sent from a Rails app.

Is there a way to open a specific app view after clicking the notification without writing native code?

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the framework you are using.

**Javascript**

```
window.history.replaceState(null, '', '/view_url/' + params);
```

**Angular JS**

```
$state.go('app.customView');
```

Comment: This is true when you are calling a URL from within the application, but how does this apply to the notification's tray since there's no references for window there

Comment: This code will go in your application's notification handler. As soon as you get a notification (in your application), change the window URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, send extra parameter in payload from server side code
Notification will trigger an event once receiving and click

Comment: You can add an example code block to help people understand.